# How to change monitor refresh rate (ATI Radeon HD 6450) on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ati

I want to change refresh rate from 60Hz to 75Hz, but xrandr shows that this card
does not support 75Hz refresh rate. On Windows this not work too. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you installed the driver. After installing driver in both if you can't change the refresh rate. That means the device doesn't support it. It is a hardware limitation. Noone can do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your video card does not support 75Hz refresh rate for current resolution. You may decrease resolution to see if 75Hz become available. If satisfied, keep it, if not, you have to change the video card for a better one.